# The usage of "&" working with printf() and scanf()

Tags: c

I've a simple question concerning the correct usage of "&" before a variable.

```
printf( "34 * 7 =  " );
scanf( "%d", &x );
printf( "The solution is 238 \n");
printf( "Your solution is %d \n\n", x );
```

I don't understand why I must use "&x" when reading the user input and why I can go without when using the printf() function. I would like to understand what is behind it.

Comment: Hint: Does `printf` change the value of `x`? How would you write a function that changes the value of `x`? What type does your parameter need to have in this case?

Comment: Do you know what `&` means?

Comment: in C language arguments are passed by value. When you output variable with printf it accepts value of your variable but for scanf() this will not work because scanf has to write into your variable and not into its copy. That is why it accepts address of variable.

Answer (score 1):

`In C, C++, and Go, a prefix "&" is a unary operator denoting the address in memory of the argument, e.g. &x, &func, &a[3].`

> I don't understand why I must use "&x" when reading the user input

Because that is how the language makers chose to define it. The `&` operator works fine even without `printf` and `scanf`.

```
int *pointer_to_x = &x;
```

Now this `scanf( "%d", pointer_to_x );` is same as `scanf( "%d", &x );`

Answer (score 1):

The scanf function takes a pointer to an int as an argument, in this case, while printf just takes the int. The & is the address-of operator.

Answer (score 1):

In *printf()* function, you are not changing value of variable '*x*', whereas in *scanf()* function you have to change the value of '*x*'. '*&x*' gives the address of *x*, this is passed to the function *scanf()*, and the value taken from user is stored in *x* using the address of x, finally when we return from function scanf() the value of x is stored with the value that user has given. If we do not use '&x', then *scanf()* function will get a local copy of variable '*x*' and the changes will not be reflected when we return from the function.

Comment: I tried to use the `scanf()` function without `&x` and it doesn't work at all. I defined `int x = 5` too see if `scanf()` really takes a local copy when `&` is not used.

Comment: Here scanf() has been designed to take address. We have to pass address, otherwise it gives an error.

Comment: If you know about call by value and call by reference, you will understand the need to pass address to a function better. Here is the link which explains call by value and reference
http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

In arguments are always passed by call by value method. So whatever argument you pass a copy is made and stored in the function.

But using pointers, we can make a function 'look-like' implementing a call by reference type of function call!.

For eg:

```
int fun(int *p)
  {
    p=1;
    return p;
  }
```

Now take an example of a function call `fun(&x);`, this function now changes the value of `x` to 1.

So in case of `scanf()` there should be an assignment happening inside the function call, and assigning a value to a variable out of scope of the function can only be done by knowing the address the variable(As the name has a scope).

So because of such reasons `scanf()` funciton is coded keeping in mind that the argument will be an address, so if you pass anything other than an address some of the code will obviously be wrong and thus results in an error.